# simple page with backbone using eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, backbone.js

Hello i would like to create a simple page using Backbone with eclipse environment. i want to create all the files seperately. like html file seperately and template(hogan) file seperately and backbone file seperately.. when i did this it the pages are not rendering..

i created all the files seperately in different folders. i want to call the template in my backbone page and render it to the html page..

my htmlpage is

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" content-type:application/javascript>
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome</h1>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.3/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/template" src = "js/templ" id ="search_template" ></script>
    <script src = "js/1.js"></script>
    <div id = "search_container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

my Backbone page is

```
/**
 * New node file
 */
    SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function(){
        this.render();
        },
    render: function(){
        // Compile the template using underscore
            var template = _.template( $("#search_template").html(), {}
        );
        // Load the compiled HTML into the Backbone "el"
            this.$el.html( template );
    }
});
    var search_view = new SearchView({ el: $("#search_container") });
```

my template page is

```
<script type="text/html" id="search_template">
<label>Search</label>
<input type="text" id="search_input" />
<input type="button" id="search_button" value="Search" />
</script>
```

Comment: 1) what's the problem? 2) for JavaScript development you better use Jetbrains WebStorm or Netbeans. Eclipse is not the best solution, believe me!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot include templates like you can with scripts. Thus, your template page is never included in the html page and $("#search_template").html() will never find the template to use.

This is because using  is a hack. The page renderer doesn't recognize the type="text/html" and silently ignores it. At the same time, the element is visible in the DOM, and can thus be accessed using the selector.

If you want to store your javascript templates in separate files you have several options:

1. Use templating in whatever server-side-language you are using (i.e. in Flask with Jinja this would be something like:

`{% include "js/templ.html" %}`

1. Do an asyncronous GET (using jQuery f.ex to fetch the template
2. Use require.js with the text extension

Comment: i tried some code using GET.. but i constantly getting errors for that. please can u include the codes using the GET method for the above code??